UI Adjustment according to Screen Size in flutter
I am a android developer i am learning flutter but here i am fighting with a commom but important issue.
In my below code last some rows is hiding. Here i divided the screen size into 10 part first 9 for gridView and the last one part for card. card is working fine but the rows is not fitting. I have giving the image here
i want to fit the UI for every screen size without any ui change. I have tried many thing but could not find any solution.
Thanks in advance
  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
  final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
  final double topPosition1 = screenHeight * 0.5;
  final double leftPosition1 = screenWidth * 0.61;
  final double topPosition2 = screenHeight * 0.56;
  final double leftPosition2 = screenWidth * 0.05;

  // Calculate the height of each part
  final double partHeight = screenHeight / 10;

  // Calculate the aspect ratio dynamically based on screen size
  final double aspectRatio = screenWidth / 10 / partHeight ;

  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('Snake and Ladder'),
    ),
    body: Center(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              // First 9 parts
              Expanded(
                flex: 9,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: GridView.builder(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 10,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 7,
                      childAspectRatio: aspectRatio,
                    ),
                    itemCount: totalCells,
                    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      final cellNumber = totalCells - index;
                      int row = ((cellNumber - 1) ~/ 10);
                      int col = (cellNumber - 1) % 10;
                      int newCellNumber;
                      if (row % 2 == 0) {
                        newCellNumber = (row + 1) * 10 - col;
                      } else {
                        newCellNumber = (row + 1) * 10 - (9 - col);
                      }
                      return _buildCell(newCellNumber, newCellNumber == _playerLocation, newCellNumber == _playerLocation2);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              // Last part
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        if (!_firstTap) {
                          _diceNumber = 6;
                          _firstTap = true;
                        } else {
                          _diceNumber = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
                        }
                        if (_buildCell1) {
                          _playerLocation += _diceNumber;
                          if (_playerLocation > totalCells) {
                            _playerLocation = totalCells;
                          }
                          if (snakes.containsKey(_playerLocation)) {
                            _playerLocation = snakes[_playerLocation]!;
                          }
                        } else {
                          _playerLocation2 += _diceNumber;
                          if (_playerLocation2 > totalCells) {
                            _playerLocation2 = totalCells;
                          }
                          if (snakes.containsKey(_playerLocation2)) {
                            _playerLocation2 = snakes[_playerLocation2]!;
                          }
                        }
                        _buildCell1 = !_buildCell1;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Card(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0, horizontal: 2.0),
                      color: _getPlayerColor(_buildCell1),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'assets/images/dice-$_diceNumber.png',
                          width: 50,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
         
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}



You're trying to reinvent a GridView using a stack with hand calculations, and getting the calcs wrong.  I suggest you just use a GridView.

Don't size your widget using MediaQuery manually (if you want to know why, see this). To get all your column and row items to fit into any device screen, simply wrap every child with Expanded.
Column(
  children: [
    for (final i in List.generate(10, (index) => index))
      Expanded( // Wrap each column item with Expanded
        child: Row(
          children: [
            for (final j in List.generate(10, (index) => index))
              Expanded( // Wrap each row item with Expanded
                child: Card(...),
              )
          ],
        ),
      )
  ],
)


The calculation for aspect ratio is wrong. You need to subtract the status bar height, app bar height and spacings mentioned in to calculate the ratio dynamically.
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenSze = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    final partHeight = screenSze.height / 10;

    // aspect ratio will be calculated using the screenheight/9-spaces and screenwidth-spaces
    // Subtract height of statusbar and app bar too if that is included: Default app bar size is 60
    final double ratio = (screenSze.width-90)/((partHeight*9)-(90+MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding.top+60));

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: partHeight * 9,
              child: GridView.builder(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 10,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                  childAspectRatio: ratio,
                ),
                itemCount: 100,
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemBuilder: (_, index) => Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text(index.toString()),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            width: 50,
            height: partHeight,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

You can implement similar logic for your use case

